# "mind having/doing something" - verb tense

Tags: verbs, tenses

"Would you mind having a look?" - I got into an argument over whether this sentence is in the Present Simple or Continuous. I would like to put this to rest.

Comment: The uncertainty is in whether 'mind' or 'having' is the main verb.

Comment: Ezra, you can [edit your question](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/439570/edit) to include relevant information, especially if you have received no answers. [Edits which could invalidate answers should be avoided.]

Answer (score 1):

> *Would you* [*mind* [*having a look*]]*?*

"Would mind having a look" is not a single constituent. "Mind having a look" is a separate constituent - a subordinate clause - functioning as complement of "would", and "having a look" is in turn a subordinate clause functioning as complement of "mind".

The modal auxiliary verb "would" heads the uppermost clause and is past tense, so it follows that syntactically the sentence as a whole is past tense.

Comment: I followed you until you said *the sentence as a whole is "past tense"* If I ask someone: "Would you mind my smoking?" OR "Would you mind if I smoked?" I am asking if something I *will* do (in the very near future) *will displease* or *annoy* that person.  What have I misunderstood?

Comment: "As a whole" means without reference to any embedded clause(s). Since it has the past tense verb "would" as head, we can say that the sentence is past tense. The other clauses are embedded ones with their own tenses.

Comment: So "Would you like some tea" is an offer made in the past?  "He would visit his sick mother" is used for an action that was repeated in the past and is no longer true in the present, but my sentence and the OP's is using "would" with "like" and "mind". Isn't *Would you mind/like* more like an idiom?

Comment: I was considering just the syntax, since the question was about tense. The OP's example is syntactically past tense, but semantically it refers to present (or future) time.